# php pdo fetchAll is empty but rowCount show

Tags: php, pdo, sybase-asa

this is my code:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
$q = "SELECT C1,C2,C3 FROM table";
$stmt = $pdo->query($q);
$nums = $stmt->rowCount();

echo "Count: ".$nums."<br>";
$erg = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($erg)
```

And the result is:

```
Count: 972<br>
Array()
```

And I have absolutly no idea what's wrong.
RowCount is correct.
I use same in an other project where it works as expected, and I can't see any difference.

Any idea what an how to check?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just get the row count from `count($erg);`

Comment: Also: Read the first section of [The PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) Where it says `rowCount()` is not guaranteed to work on a SELECT

Comment: What database are you using? @RiggsFolly I believe it does work with MySQL, for instance.

Comment: Is that really the whole script? If you have any other `fetch` or `fetchAll()` calls between `rowCount()` and `fetchAll()` the rows that they fetch will not be returned by the later `fetchAll()`.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Also, he says that `rowCount` *is* returning the correct value, it's `fetchAll()` that's wrong.

Comment: Yes that's the whole script.

Comment: Database is a Sybase Anywhere 9 and doing the select on the database returns excatly the same number of records as rowCount shows. But neither fetch or fetchAll returns any line.

Comment: So have you tried the query from the command line or whatever tool you use for sybase similiar to `phpMyAdmin` And if so how many rows does that return in the resultset

Comment: Have you tried passing obj param? $erg = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

Comment: @Niall: yes - no change

Comment: And I tried
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
No option as Sybase PDO driver does not support this

Comment: @Riggs: yes I tried with Sybase isql-Tool. It returns same number of rows and the dataset

Comment: Try wrapping it in execute? if($stmt->execute()){
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
 $erg = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
    }
}